# How to read Snappy Compressed file from S3 in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, snappy

Currently we are running MapReduce job in Hadoop in which the output is compressed into SnappyCompression. Then we are moving the output file to S3. Now I want to read the Compressed file from S3 through Java.

Comment: either you use the "same way" as in the hadoop or google found https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java

Comment: I tried the link you provide, but it doesn't say anything about reading the file. It either compress or decompress the file(even i was facing some issue using that). In s3 we read the file using getObjectContent. Is there any way we can directly read compressed file from s3.

Comment: I am trying to copy the files from s3 to local and then trying to read the Compressed file. But couldn't  find the appropriate way to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to read snappy compressed file from S3. First you should get the object content from S3. And then decompress the file.

```
    S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName,Path));
    InputStream inContent = s3object.getObjectContent();
    CompressionCodec codec = (CompressionCodec) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(SnappyCodec.class, new Configuration());
    InputStream inStream = codec.createInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inContent));
    InputStreamReader  inRead = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inRead);
    String line=null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        system.out.println(line);
    }
```